# Emploi de « en » dans « l'écriture en était méconnaissable »

Tags: sens, pronoms, possessif, en

> J'ai reçu vos lettres dit-elle vivement, en lisant sur les traits de son mari l’objection qui s’y exprimait, mais elles me parvinrent treize mois après la bataille d’Eylau ; elles étaient ouvertes, salies, l'écriture en était méconnaissable. ([Balzac](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_zlOAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=J%27ai%20re%C3%A7u%20vos%20lettres.%20L%27%C3%A9criture%20en%20%C3%A9tait%20m%C3%A9connaissable.&source=bl&ots=y7nSaG8SlV&sig=rHwcl2QNZguD36etKkNDblwAmjo&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjApPK_4vnbAhUEElAKHT17D3cQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=J'ai%20re%C3%A7u%20vos%20lettres.%20L'%C3%A9criture%20en%20%C3%A9tait%20m%C3%A9connaissable.&f=false))

Pourquoi Balzac emploie-t-il **en** ici ?

Je pense que cela veut dire *l'écriture d'elles (des lettres) était méconnaissable*. Alors *en* a-t-il un sens *possessif* ?

Comment: @editors - please refrain from transforming the Q to the point that some answers don't make much sense any more and will look unclear to future readers.

Comment: @guillaume31: I'm sorry I didn't fix the anwer in the same time. Now I hope everything is in order. To be clear, the question has to provide all the relevant context. It should have been fixed directly in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- La citation de la [question d'origine non éditée](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/30768/1)

  > J'ai reçu vos lettres … l'écriture en était méconnaissable.

  laisse penser à une possession.

  > l'écriture **des lettres** était méconnaissable
  >
  > **leur** écriture était méconnaissable
  >
  > l'écriture **en** était méconnaissable

  Cf http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en EN² I. A. 1.a) qui cite un autre exemple de cet emploi :

  > Le couloir était froid et nu, la salle d'attente, qu'on ne fit
  >   qu'entrevoir, banale. Du moins les sièges n'**en** étaient-ils pas élimés,
  >   comme chez la plupart des médecins, et n'y voyait-on pas aux murs les
  >   aquarelles habituelles.
  >
  > *-- Simenon, Les Vacances de Maigret*

  Par ailleurs, on le retrouve chez Balzac quelques pages plus loin (p.52) :

  > [...] un acte conçu en termes si crus que le Colonel sortit
  >   brusquement de l'étude après **en** avoir entendu la lecture.
- Cependant, la phrase entière

  > elles étaient ouvertes, salies, l'écriture en était méconnaissable

  suggère aussi la cause (toujours I. A. 1.a)).

  > l'écriture était méconnaissable **parce qu'** elles avaient été ouvertes,
  >   salies

Etant donné que ni l'ouverture ni la salissure ne me paraissent des raisons suffisantes pour que *l'écriture* d'une lettre soit *méconnaissable*, je pencherais plutôt pour une encre distordue et effacée par les éléments et le temps (à défaut, comme le soupçonne Rosine, d'avoir été falsifiée) donc le premier emploi.

Un autre indice se trouve peut-être dans la virgule qui précède et qui pourrait indiquer une énumération plutôt qu'une causalité - laquelle aurait plutôt bénéficié de deux points ou d'un point-virgule.

Comment: Personnellement je penche lourdement pour la cause, qui n'est pas seulement le fait qu'elles soient ouvertes et salies, mais surtout les 13 mois de délai.

Comment: L'Histoire nous a légué des manuscrits vieux de plusieurs siècles dont l'écriture est restée parfaitement reconnaissable... cela ne constitue pas, me semble-t-il, une raison en soi. Il nous faudrait probablement l'avis d'un spécialiste de Balzac ici.

Answer (score 5):

Le "en" ici signifie "à cause de" en quelque sorte. Les raisons cités précédemment, à savoir :

> elles me parvinrent treize mois après [...], elles étaient ouvertes, salies

sont donc nécessairement les causes de l'écriture méconnaissable. Avec "en" ça ne fait aucun doute alors que sans, on pourrait imaginer que l'écriture était méconnaissable pour une autre raison.

Dans un autre contexte :

> J'ai fait du sport et j'en étais exténué.
>
> J'ai fait du sport et j'étais exténué.

Dans la seconde phrase, on se retrouve avec une succession d'évènement plutôt qu'un enchaînement de cause et d'effet.

Comment: Alors n'y a-t-il pas un sens possessif de en ?

Comment: Non ni dans ce contexte ni dans aucun autre.

Comment: Merci. Ou puis-je trouver plus de renseignement par rapport à cet emploi de **en** ?

Comment: Ici par exemple :  https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/en/29043?q=En#28919

Comment: Parfait, merci bien:-)!

Comment: Dans la phrase: «J'ai fait du sport et j'en étais exténué.» On peut plus facilement *en* tirer que l'état exténué du sujet est relié au fait que ce dernier a fait du sport. (Ma phrase est ainsi un autre exemple de cette situation.)

Comment: Si, bien sur qu'il a autre part un sens possessif, e.g. dans *J'en oublie le nom*.

Comment: Dans j'en oublie le nom on pourrait aussi remplacer par :  il est si peu connu que j'en oublie le nom. Aucun sens de possession ici, toujours la cause et l'effet.

Comment: D'ailleurs la phrase "j'en oublie le nom" toute seule n'a pas de sens.

Comment: @Maestro31 "en" peut bel et bien marquer la possession : *"[Dans des constr. où en a valeur de compl. de nom marquant la possession, l'appartenance]"* http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?21;s=1253440770;r=1;nat=;sol=10; I 1..a) 4.

Answer (score 0):

"***en***" signifie simplement "***de cela***": "*L'écriture **en** était méconnaissable*" signifie "l'écriture ***de cela*** était méconnaissable" et ***cela*** désigne bien évidemment le sujet énoncé dans la proposition précédente: les "***lettres***".

*"- Voulez-vous du café? - Oui, J'**en** veux bien."* signifie "*je veux bien de **cela***", c'est à dire **du café**.

Sur ce point en tout cas, le pronom "***en***" rend le français plus concis que l'anglais, qui doit utiliser des formules plus longues comme *"this","them", "some"* etc...